# adding word count of string check into existing IF statement

Tags: javascript

I am trying to add another condition to that statement, they checks the length of 'w' and if its more than 1 word then the value of 'text' is 'error more than 1 word' and return;

here is existing code:

```
    function Check()
{
    p = document.getElementById('p').value
    w = document.getElementById('w').value  
  
   
   if (p == '' || w == ''){

        document.getElementById('text').value = 'error';
        return;
    }  

    else
    {
        let xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
                var j = JSON.parse(this.response);
                result = j.answer;
                show();
            }
        };

        xhttp.open("GET",URL+"?p="+p+"&w="+w);
        xhttp.send();

        return;
    }
    
}
```

edit got solution using .split(" ").length

Comment: you can group conditions and add logical comparison between them; eg: ((a == b) || (b !=c)) ? x : y

Comment: 3 options... 1. check with `strpos()` if you have a space. 2. You remove all space before sending a request. 3. use `encodeURIComponent` that will change space to %20.